# Making a polygon smaller

Tags: javascript, canvas

How would I go about making this polygon smaller so it would fit in a 800X300 canvas area?

```
 context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(200,0);
 context.lineTo(400,0);
 context.lineTo(600,200);
 context.lineTo(600,400);
 context.lineTo(400,600);
 context.lineTo(200,600);
 context.lineTo(0,400);
 context.lineTo(0,200);
 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
```

I cannot seem to figure out what numbers need to be changed.

Comment: Uh. Multiply all the numbers by .5?

Comment: I need to make it smaller not bigger.

Comment: Which is what that would do.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`scale()`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_scale.asp) method.

```
context.scale(x, x);
```

where `x` is the factor to scale by.

Answer (score 2):

You can either replot your lines, or the quickest way would be to use the scale method on your context like this

```
 context.scale(0.5,0.5);
```

That would make it half the size, so a full example would be

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var context=c.getContext("2d");
 context.scale(0.5,0.5);

context.beginPath();
 context.moveTo(200,0);
 context.lineTo(400,0);
 context.lineTo(600,200);
 context.lineTo(600,400);
 context.lineTo(400,600);
 context.lineTo(200,600);
 context.lineTo(0,400);
 context.lineTo(0,200);

 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
```

See jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/XLW2P/1/